# pasar variables hidden y recuperarla en otra pagina

Tags: php

tengo un calendario de tareas y una etiqueta "Realizar"

este es mi codigo

```html
<section id="form">
    <form class="contact_form" ACTION="prueba.php" METHOD="POST">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Calendario de Tareas</h2>
            </li>
            <?php
$sql="select Nombre from login where user_name ='$usuario' ";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$user = $result->fetch_assoc()['Nombre'];
            ?>
            <?php
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$sql="select * from tareas where Auditor ='$user'";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");
  
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3>";

/*Priemro los encabezados*/
 echo "<tr>
         <th colspan=16 BGCOLOR='#BCC1C2' WIDTH='10%' face='Georgia' align='center'> Auditorias Programadas </th>
       <tr BGCOLOR='#DADDDE'>
         <th class='estilo1'> ID </th><th class='estilo1'> Auditor </th><th class='estilo1'> Auditoria </th>
         <th class='estilo1'> Fecha Deseada </th><th class='estilo1'> Fecha limite </th><th class='estilo1'> Estado </th><th class='estilo1'> Realizar </th>
      </tr>";

/*Y ahora todos los registros */
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row["ID"];
    $Auditor = $row["Auditor"];
    $auditoria = $row["Auditoria"];
    $Fdeseada = $row["Fdeseada"];
    $Flimite = $row["Flimite"];
 echo "<tr>
         <td align='right' class='estilo1'> $id </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $Auditor </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $auditoria </td>
         <input type='hidden' name='auditoria' value='".$auditoria."' />
        <td class='estilo1'> $Fdeseada </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $Flimite </td>
             <td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
                 <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='prueba.php'> Realizar </A></td>
              <input type='hidden' name='oculto' value='".$id."' />
                     
                 
      </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
    </form>        
</section>
```

y quiero pasar el id y auditoria seleccionada a otra pagina en php

pagina 2

```html
<?php
$Operarios= $_GET['auditoria'];
$id = ['oculto'];
echo $Operarios;
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías, por favor, explicarnos mejor el funcionamiento de tu página? ¿De qué modo quieres que los datos se envíen a la otra página? ¿Por formulario? ¿Por link? ¿Desde fuera de la tabla, o es una acción por cada registro de la tabla?

Comment: seria por $_POST solo quiero mandar el id del rengron que selecciono el usuario

Comment: Ok. ¿Y lo estarias enviando al mismo destino que el `action` del `form`, o a una página distinta?

Comment: al mismo a pruebas.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes probar agregando tu variable $id al url y luego lo obtienes via $_GET['id'] en otra avista

En tu código podrías actualizar la etiqueta a :

```
<a href='prueba.php?id=".$id."'> Realizar </a>
```

Y en la pagina 2:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];//variable con el id pasado
```

Te recomendaria usar mejor un metodo POST para no pasar las variables por el URL, pero de manera funcional sirve.

Espero que te haya servido!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder enviar por `POST` lo ideal es que envíes el formulario como tal. Y ya que necesitas enviar los valores de sólo 1 de los registros en la tabla/grilla, puedes capturar dichos valores mediante Javascript y asignarlos a los controles ocultos, para entonces forzar el envío del formulario.

Tú ya tienes la idea de los controles ocultos, pero en tu caso, no deben estar por cada renglón, sino sólo una vez. Si enviaras el formulario como está, te llegarían al otro lado sin duda los valores de los campos ocultos, pero con el valor de sólo el último renglón. (Si quisieras en efecto enviarlos todos, tendrías que nombrar esos controles ocultos en modo arreglo (`name="oculto[]"`), para que al otro lado lleguen como `array`. Pero no es tu caso ahora.)

En tu formulario, los campos ocultos tienen que ir sólo una vez:

```
<section id="form">
    <form class="contact_form" ACTION="prueba.php" METHOD="POST" id="formulario">
        <input type="hidden" name="auditoria" id="auditoria" />
        <input type="hidden" name="oculto" id="oculto" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Calendario de Tareas</h2>
            </li>
```

Fíjate que le di un "id" al formulario. Será necesario después.

Luego, en cada renglón, aplicas un manejador para el evento `onclick` de cada fila. Puedes hacerlo en la etiqueta `<tr>`, `<td>` o en un botón, o incluso sobre el link que ya tienes... Tú eliges dónde. Yo te mostraré el ejemplo sobre la etiqueta `<tr>`:

```
<?php
/*Y ahora todos los registros */
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row["ID"];
    $Auditor = $row["Auditor"];
    $auditoria = $row["Auditoria"];
    $Fdeseada = $row["Fdeseada"];
    $Flimite = $row["Flimite"];
 echo "<tr onclick=\"enviarRegistro('".$auditoria."', '".$id."')\">
         <td align='right' class='estilo1'> $id </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $Auditor </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $auditoria </td>
        <td class='estilo1'> $Fdeseada </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $Flimite </td>
             <td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
                 <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='prueba.php'> Realizar </A></td>
      </tr>";
} 
?>
```

Donde la función Javascript `enviarRegistro()` sería algo como:

```
function enviarRegistro(auditoria, id)
{
  document.getElementById("auditoria").value = auditoria;
  document.getElementById("id").value = id;
  document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
}
```

Por supuesto puedes cambiar el uso de Javascript básico por JQuery, o como quieras. Mi intención es darte una idea de la lógica, tú verás cómo la implementas ;)

Comment: He utilizado esta forma de enviar los formularios, pero es un poco trabajosa. Me parece buena para enviar datos "simulando" un POST, evitando asi que se vean por URL los valores

Comment: La verdad, hay muchas formas de enviar los datos sin que se vean por la barra de direcciones: usando los ya casi obsoletos `<iframe>`; enviando los valores con Ajax; incluso usando sesiones de PHP; etc...... uff hay muchos caminos, supongo que depende de cada quien elegir el que le parezca más adecuado :)

Comment: Como sea, mi respuesta va a lo que el usuario preguntó y luego especificó en sus comentarios: enviar los datos por POST, vale decir, que no se vean por la URL. Si no fuera así, las otras respuestas sirven al 100% como solución (usando GET).

Answer (score 0):

Como tal NO importa el tipo: `hidden`, `text`, `number`.

Ocurre que son inputs con un "`name`" por lo tanto debes hacer un `POST` de ellos. A menos que los pases por url con un `HREF`, que para este caso si se usa `GET`

Quedaria algo asi en el action de tu archivo llamado `prueba.php`

```
$id = $_POST["id"]
$auditoria = $_POST["auditoria"]
```

Ahora bien, quieres pasar esos datos desde una tabla, supongo querras un boton que aparezca en cada columna, este deberia ser asi:

```
<a href="prueba.php?id='.$id.'"></a>
```

En el archivo `prueba.php` usaremos lo siguiente

```
$id = $_GET["id"]
```